# Why form_for use incorrect REST url_helpers for namespaced controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app have a partial that contains a form shared between the new and edit action:

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>

....

<% end %>
```

These action are of a controller (called **customers**) namespaced (called **admin**), if try to run the code show the error when execute form_for:

> undefined method `customer_path'

Have resolved this using:

> <%= form_for :customer, @customer do
>   |f| %>
>
> ```
> ....
>
> <% end %>
> ```

Now the form is generated with correct url when is called by **new** action but when generated by **edit**  the form url is "/admin/customers/1/**edit**" instead of **update**. If submit the form show the error:

> No route matches "/admin/customers/1/edit"

but in routes.rb have:

> namespace :admin do
>
> resources :customers
>
> end

and rake:routes show all the REST urls:

> admin_customers GET    /admin/customers(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/customers"}
>                  POST   /admin/customers(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/customers"} 
>   new_admin_customer GET /admin/customers/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/customers"}
>   edit_admin_customer GET/admin/customers/:id/edit(.:format){:action=>"edit",:controller=>"admin/customers"}
>   admin_customer GET    /admin/customers/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show",:controller=>"admin/customers"}
>                 PUT    /admin/customers/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/customers"}
>                 DELETE /admin/customers/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy",:controller=>"admin/customers"}

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @customer] do |f| %>
```

Comment: the generated form action is "/admin/customers/1", if submit return to index page without any change to record.

Comment: it is correct action, actually. And what did you expect? If nothing changes - there is a problem in your controller code

Comment: Ops, sorry, a logic error in update method, now works. Thanks.